# Neo4j - unable to craete a relationship using cypher in java

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-java-api

I am failing to execute the cipher query through java while creating a relationship. It is not throwing any error, but no relationships are created. Tried with other cipher query to return a node, which is returning perfectly. But unable to figure-out the reason for relationships not being created.

Here goes my code:

```
public static void addrelation(String node1, String node2, int cocr) {
        try (Transaction tx = graphdb.beginTx();
                Result result = graphdb.execute("MATCH(a{word:\"" + node1
                        + "\"}),(b{word:\"" + node2 + "\"})"
                        + "CREATE a-[r:coocr{val:" + cocr + "}]->(b)"
                        + "CREATE a<-[s:coocr{val:" + cocr + "}]-(b)"
                        + "RETURN r,s")) {
                }
            }
```

Comment: As an aside you should use parameters for performance, security, and to avoid string concatenation headaches: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-parameters.html

Answer (score 1):

Adding tx.success() line made changes into the database.

```
    public static void addrelation(String node1, String node2, int cocr) {
            try (Transaction tx = graphdb.beginTx();
                    Result result = graphdb.execute("MATCH(a{word:\"" + node1
                            + "\"}),(b{word:\"" + node2 + "\"})"
                            + "CREATE a-[r:coocr{val:" + cocr + "}]->(b)"
                            + "CREATE a<-[s:coocr{val:" + cocr + "}]-(b)"
                            + "RETURN r,s")) {

   //Adding this line resolved the issue.                 
                           tx.success();

                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your `MATCH` matching anything?  If not it won't created the relationships and will return successfully.  Maybe remove the two `CREATE` lines and `RETURN a, b` to see.

Comment: Yes, Match is matching with those two words. The same query is running fine without java.

Comment: Match returning two nodes when I return a,b instead of relation's  like this  {b=Node[183], a=Node[221]} @Brain Underwood

Comment: Maybe you need to commit your transaction.  Java's not my strong suit, sorry ;)

Comment: Yes, commited my transaction and the changes affected. Thanks @Brain Underwood